# How to display logs in node.js?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I run my application is written in Node.js using CMD (Windows OS).

```
node server.js
```

There is `console.log('Client connected...');` in server file.

But I dont see logs in CMD whene I application is working. How can I fix it?

My code is:

```
var express = require('express');  
var app = express();  
var server = require('http').createServer(app);  
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/bower_components'));  
app.get('/', function(req, res,next) {  
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

server.listen(4200);  


io.on('connection', function(client) {  
    console.log('Client connected...');
});
```

Comment: Please update your question with the relevant code. Generally, such kind of behaviour happens when you have added console.log in some API method and you are not making any call to that API route.

Comment: [I can't reproduce the problem](http://imgur.com/a/Da7RM), you need to provide a real [MCVE]

Comment: I made changes in question

Comment: This may be node version and windows version specific. Normally win32 applications don't direct stdout to the console - you need to specifically build your app as a console app. Some version of node/windows combo may be affecting console.log

Comment: where is `console.log("Test")` as told in post?

Comment: Sorry, it was `console.log('Client connected...');`

Comment: did you try to use console.log in app.get?
and where is your client side code for socket io?

Comment: @slebetman - When I run node.js on win32 from a command window, it outputs all console.log statements right to that console window so I'm not sure what you're talking about.

Comment: Have you got any client connected to your server? If not then you don't see any console.log messages